# how to delete a particular section of file

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

**Goal:**

> To delete a specific part (from lower_range to upper_range) of file

So far i have managed to select parts from file which i want to delete.

```
fh = open("sample.txt", "r")
lower_range, upper_range = [int(x) for x in raw_input("enter both ranges").split(',')]
lines = fh.readlines()
i = 0
for line in lines:
 if (upper_range >= i) and (lower_range <= i):
    print(lines[i])
    i += 1
 else:
    i += 1
fh.close()
```

**sample.txt**

```
The possibility of losing helium forever poses 
the threat of a real crisis because its unique
qualities are extraordinarily difficult, if not
impossible to duplicate (certainly, no biosynthetic
ersatz product is close to approaching the point of
feasibility for helium, even as similar developments
continue apace for oil and coal).Helium is even cheerfully
derided as a “loner” element since it does not adhere
to other molecules like its cousin, hydrogen.According
to Dr. Lee Sobotka, helium is the “most noble of gases,
meaning it’s very stable and non-reactive for the most
part … it has a closed electronic configuration, a very
tightly bound atom.It is this coveting of its own electrons
that prevents combination with other elements’.Another
important attribute is helium’s unique boiling point,
which is lower than that for any other element.
```

if lower_range = 1 & upper_range = 5

**output**

```
the threat of a real crisis because its unique
qualities are extraordinarily difficult, if not
impossible to duplicate (certainly, no biosynthetic
ersatz product is close to approaching the point of
feasibility for helium, even as similar developments
```

Pretty lazy to delete lines manually, so any ideas how to do it ? Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution reads the file into memory, which is suboptimal.

You can use `enumerate()` to loop over the line number along with the line, and compound comparison (`x < y < z`) for the condition. You may wish to adjust `<=` to `<` as you like.

We're also using `yield` to define a generator function that can be iterated over.

```py
def filter_lines(filename, start_line, end_line):
    with open(filename) as f:
        for i, line in enumerate(f):
            if start_line <= i <= end_line:
                yield line

for line in filter_lines('sample.txt', 1, 5):
    print(line)
```

EDIT: If you want to write the new lines into a new file, simply:

```py
with open('sample2.txt', 'w') as f:
    for line in filter_lines('sample.txt', 1, 5):
        print(line, file=f)
```